# Listar Serviços via CMD

Tags: windows, cmd, services

Estou usando o comando **wmic service get displayname,name,state** para Listar Serviços do Windows.

Gostaria de saber se é possível listar via CMD um ou mais Serviços Específicos.

Neste cenário quero listar o Status dos Serviços FirebirdServerDefaultInstance e SQLServerAgent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a cláusula `where`, da seguinte maneira:

```
wmic service where 'name like "FirebirdServerDefaultInstance " or name like "SQLServerAgent"' get displayname,name,state
```

Comment: Show! Muito Obrigado Murillo.

Comment: Pode aceitar essa resposta?

Answer (score 0):

Sei que essa Pergunta já é muito antiga, porém você pode também usar o seguinte comando:

```
wmic service get displayname,name,state | findstr "nome_serviço"
```

Ou até mesmo:

```
sc queryex type=service state=all | find /i "nome_serviço"
```